# Deletar registro firebase

Tags: android, firebase, crud

Olá,
Leio os registros do firebase e os insiro  uma array de objetos. A classe Json possui apenas os campos de negócio e não possui o campo chave. Para deletar um registro avalio que a Melhor abordagem seria alterar a classe Json e inserir o campo chave.
Esta é a melhor abordagem?
Obrigado.

//Desejo excluir o registro neste método

```
 listviewCompras.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                                   int pos, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Log.v("long clicked","pos: " + pos);

                        return true;
                    }
                })
```

;

// Código que recupera os dados do banco.

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                                //habilitando o botao pata evitsr dula entras
                                buttonSave.setEnabled(true);

                                ParcelaCartao parcela = new ParcelaCartao();
                                ArrayList<ParcelaCartao> array = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren())
                                {

                                    parcela = childSnapshot.getValue(ParcelaCartao.class);
                                    array.add(parcela);
                                }                   

                                monta_listview(array);
```

> Classe ParcelaCartao

```
import com.google.firebase.database.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
/**
 * Created by Belal on 2/23/2016.
 */
//@JsonIgnoreProperties
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class ParcelaCartao
{

    private String descricao;
    private long parcelas;
    private double valor;
    private String datacompra;
    private String dataultparcela;

    public ParcelaCartao(String descricao, long parcelas ,double valor, String datacompra, String dataultparcela)
    {
        setDescricao(descricao);
        setParcelas(parcelas);
        setValor(valor);
        setDatacompra(datacompra);  
        setDataultparcela(dataultparcela);
    }


    public ParcelaCartao() {
        /*Blank default constructor essential for Firebase*/
    }

    public void setParcelas(long parcelas)
    {
        this.parcelas = parcelas;
    }

    public long getParcelas()
    {
        return parcelas;
    }



    public String getDescricao()
    {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao)
    {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }


    public double getValor()
    {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(double valor)
    {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public String getDatacompra()
    {
        return datacompra;
    }


    public void setDatacompra(String data_compra)
    {
        this.datacompra = data_compra;

    }


    public String getDataultparcela()
    {
        return dataultparcela;
    }

    public void setDataultparcela(String datault_parcela)
    {
        this.dataultparcela = datault_parcela;

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Compra: " +  descricao +
            "\n num_parcelas: " + parcelas + " valor: " + valor + 
            "\n data compra: " + datacompra + 
            "\n data ult parcela: " + dataultparcela;
    }   
    }
```

Comment: poderia colocar uma parte do codigo para melhor entendimento do seu problema

Comment: Olá inseri a classe. Observe que ela não possui o campo chave.

Comment: Não sei como é a estrutura do seu projeto, mas poate o codigo da tela onde fica o método deletar

Comment: Olá inseri os métodos de recuperação e de delecao dos dados.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar a sua chave à sua classe, mas não guardar essa chave na database. Porque se guardar, a chave irá ocupar mais espaço na sua database e será uma repetição (desnecessária) da chave que já se encontra lá.

Para fazer isso, adicione a anotação `@Exclude` para os getters e setters da chave:

```
    private String chave;

    @Exclude
    public String getChave(){
        return chave;
    }

    @Exclude
    public void setChave(String novaChave){
        chave = novaChave;
    }
```

E inicialize esta chave quando você estiver lendo os dados:

```
                                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren())
                                {

                                    parcela = childSnapshot.getValue(ParcelaCartao.class);
                                    parcela.setChave(childSnapshot.getKey());
                                    array.add(parcela);
                                }
```